# How do I override the og:image for Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

I'm setting up Article Rich Pins for a site.  When the URL is shared on Pinterest it correctly sees it as an article, and pulls the og:image from the metadata, which is the featured image from the post.

Most places our content is consumed a landscape image is best, but for Pinterest I'd like like to use something slimmer (I've got a thumbnail that is square that would work better).  I do not want to change the featured image (too many knock-on effects).

How can I override the image for Pinterest?
Is there a tag that will trump og:image?

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED - it was actually pulling the image URL from the sharing button, not og:image.